# if A and C are both upper triangular matrices, and AB=C

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If A and C are both upper triangular matrices, and $AB=C$, does that obligating that B is an upper triangular matrix as well?

Comment: Try the case A=C=0.

Comment: Invertible upper triangular matrices form a group. So if the matrices are invertible, B is upper triangular as well. If not, then we can't say anything about B as @B.W. pointed out.